# how to make redux store to listen to cookies?

Tags: reactjs, cookies, redux, react-redux

I have an application with react and redux.

I want to make my redux store to listen to cookies.

Whenever the cookie gets expired, after a certain period of time, I want to dispatc an action which will update the corresponding store value as well.

For example
Whenever the user log in to the site, lets say we are generating one authentication token and we want to store it in cookie and set a expiry time of 2 hrs.

Once the 2hrs is completed, I want to to dispatch an action which will update the redux store data "isAuthenticated" to false

The reducer may look like this

```
export const user(state ={}, action)
{
   case "cookie_expired":
    return {...state, isAuthenticated: false}
}
```

So that i can have single source of truth i.e redux store which can listen to cookies as well

**Tried**
Using setInterval, I can watch the availability off cookie but that will be a workaround.

Is there any redux way to achieve this?

Comment: There is no built in event or callback for cookie expiry or value change. SetInterval seems to be the only option.

Comment: Can the downvoter please share the reason behind downvoting?

Answer (score 0):

I would instead just save some datetime value within Redux, `sessionValidUntil`, at the time when you assign `isAuthenticated` to true.  Set this new redux value to the current time + 2 hours.

Then, wherever you are currently checking `isAuthenticated`, I would instead check a new function that looks like this;

```
(reduxState) => {
    return (reduxState.isAuthenticated && new Date() < reduxState.sessionValidUntil);
}
```

Comment: yeah.. thats what the whole point is I dont want to keep checking isAuthenticated.

Whenever the cookie gets expired, i want my redux store to get updated automatically

Comment: lets say isAUthenticated is set to true and sessionValidUntil is set to some time. 

Now lets all the components are already rendered and no component is updating.

now even if i set the value to (reduxState.isAuthenticated && new Date() < reduxState.sessionValidUntil), it is only a redux store listener.

as the isauthenticated is true, it wont even come to this phase.

Hope i clarified your doubt.

if not, provide a working jsfiddle for your solution.

Comment: I mean.... no... But it sounds like you've got it all figured out, so I won't bother trying to help you further.

Comment: Hey I need your help. I just had some doubts related to sessionvaliduntill.
It would be really helpful if you can provide a working jsfiddle solution.